# Are there any split USB cables that can power two devices?

Tags: power-supply, usb, raspberry-pi

https://www.adafruit.com/products/501

I wanted to use this to drive two devices simultaneously (raspberry pi and peripheral).

I would like to have a y-cable - one end with a male Micro USB B-Type connector and a regular USB male A connector, and the other end with another regular USB male - A connector.

I was looking at y cables, but could not find such a cable :(!

Could I just get a y-cable with the male A's on one end and wrap an extender up the main wire?

Thanks...

Comment: This has nothing to do with electrical engineering or electronics design. This is off topic per the [faq].

Comment: An alternative approach is a "passive USB hub" with a cable to each device. Or an active USB hub if the devices require more power than a single USB port supplies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably won't find a cable like that because USB does't support devices in parallel on the same cable. You'll either have to

- make your own cable and remember that it won't support data
- use two wall warts
- or find one with double outputs like König IPD-POWER40:

[image: König IPD-POWER40]

Comment: I was basically going to make my own cable and just remember that it won't support data ...  I just needed to hear it from someone who knew this was the only way!

Comment: Now that I mention it... there's not any way to make a USB cable other than stringing together various cables in a Frankenstein way, is there?

Comment: http://www.instructables.com/id/Creating-you-own-USB-cables/